# export image on a label in java swing

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage, imageicon

My java code a image on a label which in this code is b2. What I want to do is when the user hits the button for the image that is on the label to be exported. Right now there is a error stating

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   class javax.swing.ImageIcon cannot be cast to class
>   java.awt.image.BufferedImage (javax.swing.ImageIcon and
>   java.awt.image.BufferedImage are in module java.desktop of loader
>   'bootstrap')  at time.simple$1.actionPerformed(simple.java:51).

Line 51 is unscaledButtonImage = (BufferedImage) icon;. So there is a runtime error every time I try to run this code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;  

class simple {
    Frame f;  
      JLabel b2=new JLabel("");;  

    simple() throws IOException{ 

        f=new JFrame();  
        b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/johnzalubski/Desktop/dropIn/Complete-Audi-Buying-Guide-gear-patrol-lead-full.jpg"));
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Exported");
        File file = new File("aa.png");
        f.add(b2,BorderLayout.CENTER);  
        f.add(b3,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
        f.setSize(400,500);  
        f.setVisible(true);  

        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        BufferedImage unscaledButtonImage;
        Icon icon = b2.getIcon();



        unscaledButtonImage = (BufferedImage) icon;





                BufferedImage scaledButtonImage =
                        new BufferedImage(400, 1000, unscaledButtonImage.getType());
                    Graphics g = scaledButtonImage.createGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(unscaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 400, 1000, null);

                    g.dispose();


                    b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledButtonImage));

                try {
                    ImageIO.write(scaledButtonImage, "png",file);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }  
       public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String ImagePath)
        {
            ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(ImagePath);
            Image img = MyImage.getImage();
            Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(b2.getWidth(), b2.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
            return image;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        new simple();  

        }  

    }
```

Comment: `unscaledButtonImage = (BufferedImage) icon;` this is where you fail - because `ImageIcon` is to compatible with `BufferedImage`. You should be able to use `ImageIcon#getImage` which should be easier to paint to the `Graphics` context or use `ImageIcon#paintIcon` to paint the icon to the `Graphics` context

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what to write instead of unscaledButtonImage = (BufferedImage) icon;

Comment: You need to do a few things - first, read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) - You will find that `ImageIcon` has a `getImage` method, which returns an instance of `java.awt.Image`. You will find that [`Graphics#drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) actually expects an instance of `java.awt.Image` - so problem solved, you don't need to "cast" `ImageIcon` to `BufferedImage` at all - just replace it with `getImage`

Comment: Next, take the time do some due diligence with your problem, a quick [google using "java convert ImageIcon to bufferedimage"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+convert+imageicon+to+bufferedimage&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) returns a wealth of information - respectfully, your problem isn't unquie and has been asked and solved a number of times before